# Accessing variables in stdClass with period in key

Tags: php, class, variables, stdclass

I have the following returned after setting up a SOAP call to add a new user to a web service.

```
object(stdClass)#342 (1) { ["Subscriber.AddResult"]=> object(stdClass)#341 (2) { ["Code"]=> int(0) ["Message"]=> string(7) "Success" } }
```

Now I need to access the Message variable, but I can't seem to get the damn thing. I can;t seem to var_dump the Subscriber.AddRedult part because of that period.

Comment: `$obj->{'Subscriber.AddResult'}`

Comment: @ComFreek It's not the best question, but it's hard to say it is an exact duplicate of a question referring to a different character issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclose the property name in mustaches and quotes:

```
echo $object->{'Subscriber.AddResult'};
```